# Prevent grandchild calling its grandparent's methods

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a simple parent and base class:

```
class X
{
public:
 virtual void Method(){...}
};

class Z : public X
{
public:
 virtual void Method(){ X::Method(); }
};
```

I want to refactor this so a new class `Y` sits in-between in the class hierarchy, so `Z : Y`, `Y : X`. `Z::Method()` should now call `Y::Method()` not `X::Method()`.  But if I don't change this, it still compiles. In truth, I have a lot of such methods and it's very easy to miss a call to `X::...` when refactoring which would lead to hard-to-find bugs.

Is there a way I can get the compiler to alert me, in other words, make `X`'s methods accessible to `Y`, but hidden from `Z`?

To clarify, this may only be a temporary change while I am doing the refactoring to make sure I don't miss anything.

Comment: Usual answer: Composition? Or private inheritance? Maybe a bit of context would be good, why you need this.

Comment: @idmean but then `Y` has to implement pass-through methods for every method in `X` it doesn't override...?

Comment: So you want Y to override methods from X in such a way that Z can no longer call them. Did I get that right?

Comment: If you want `X`'s methods to be available to `Y` but hidden from `Z`, you can change them from `public` to `private` but make `Y` a `friend` class. I wouldn't suggest leaving it that way permanently but if your goal is to flush out that behavior it would have that effect.

Comment: @idmean no, I want to make sure that all the places `Z` calls the super-class method in `X`, is updated to call `Y`.

Answer (score 7):

> But if I don't change this, it still compiles. In truth I have a lot of such methods and it's very easy to miss a call to X::... when refactoring which would lead to hard to find bugs.
>
> To clarify, **this may only be a temporary change while I am doing the refactoring** to make sure I don't miss anything.

As you are describing *"when refactoring"*, you could temporarily add an incomplete type `X` to `Z` that shadows the super class `X` up the hierarchy:

```
class Z : public Y {
private:
    struct X;  // TODO(Mr. Boy): remove after finishing re-factoring.
public:
    void Method() override { X::Method(); }  // error! Z::X is incomplete
};
```

Any qualified use of `X::...` in `Z` will fail as lookup resolves to the incomplete nested type `X`.